# onMouseover and onMouseOut Event Handle in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am beginner of React-Js and I stuck some event handling onmouserover and onmouseout.

```
let showUpdateRow = () => {}

let hideUpdateRow = () => {}

let bodyContent = props.linkData.map((data, index) => {
  return (
    <tr key={index} onMouseOver={showUpdateRow} onMouseOut={hideUpdateRow}>
      <td>{data.comments}</td>
      <td>
        {data.link}
        <div className="updateRow" style={{ display: 'none' }}>
          <MdEdit className="editRow" />
          <MdDelete className="deleteRow" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
})
```

onMouseOver Event, I want to show updateRow Div and OnMouseOut Event, I want to hide updateRow Div.

I need to show only updateRow div which currently mouseover inside tr. If I use ref property but on mouseover all updateRowDiv will show.

I need some help , Thanks.

Comment: you can track currently active row id in a private variable(say `this._activeRowId`) and display or hide a row inside bodyContent's loop by comparing row id to `this._acriveRowId`

Comment: is there a reason you want to do it in React? would you consider using css instead? example: https://codesandbox.io/s/x943nky4yq

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly. 
You could declare a state for `showUpdateRow` and use that to show/hide your row.

So it will look something like

```
state = {
  showUpdateRow: false,
};

showHideUpdateRow =  (value) => {
  this.setState({showUpdateRow : value})
}
```

and in the bodycontent you can use

```
onMouseOver={showHideUpdateRow(true)} onMouseOut={showHideUpdateRow(false)}
```

and then in the `updateRow` style

```
style={{ display: `${this.state.showUpdateRow ? 'block' : 'none'}` }}
```